# How can I play the iOS/Android tutorial map on PC?

Tags: terraria

I recently downloaded the mobile Terraria app for Android, and quickly noticed the tutorial map has a buncha secrets/easter eggs in it (such as a lucky horseshoe off the left cliff, and a little furnished room with hellstone in the far lower left corner).

I'd like to explore the map more fully, but doing so with a copper pickaxe is rather tedious. How can I play the tutorial map with my decked-out PC character?

Comment: Interesting idea! I managed to grab the tutorial world off my phone, but sadly the PC version won't load it. If anyone else wants to try and hex-edit the incompatibilities away, it's in `assets/Tutorial.world`.

Comment: Maybe this will be added in the 1.2 release coming October 1st.

Comment: Not sure yet either, but at least get a gold pickaxe.
Also if you built a "sky bridge" in the deep to the left, the old man will show up and allows you to battle skeletron. I haven't found the dungeon though. Have you tried copying and renaming it to another world, so you can at least play it with your regular (and loaded out) character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can't. Only iOS Android and Kindle versions can use the tutorial map.